# ng-repeat - trying to figure out best way to set up what I'm trying to do

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok, so here is what I am trying to do:
 - I am building a portfolio slider that shows images for all of my projects.
 - Each project has multiple images that I would like to show on its own slide.
 - For example, after you slide through project 1's images (each on their own slide), the next slide will start with project 2's first image and so on.
 - I can do this the long way, but I am trying to group my projects into their own objects, including their name, the client it was for and the images associated to that project.
 - My end goal is to have an organized object, but all the images are gathered and shown in the slider one after the other. When a new project's image is shown, I also would like to know which project object I am on so I can get the project name, index and client it was for, so that I can change info on the page.
 - I hope this is not too confusing.

Here is what I have right now for the object

**JS:**

```
mainApp.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
    $scope.portfolio = [
        {name:'Portfolio 1', image:['images/test_1a.png','images/test_1b.png','images/test_1c.png'], client:'Client 1'},
        {name:'Portfolio 2', image:['images/test_2a.png','images/test_2b.png'], client:'Client 2'},
        {name:'Portfolio 3', image:['images/test_3a.png','images/test_3b.png','images/test_3c.png'], client:'Client 3'}
    ];
});
```

This is what I was starting to try when I got stuck. Obviously, this is not what I need, but it let's you see where I am trying to go.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- slide -->
        <div ng-repeat="work in portfolio">
            <div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="img in work.image">
                <!-- image -->
                <img class="full_width" src="{{ img }}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any and all help it super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there.. Your issue is using src instead of `ng-src`.

Try:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- slide -->
        <div ng-repeat="work in portfolio">
            <div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="img in work.image">
                <!-- image -->
                <img class="full_width" ng-src="{{ img }}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```